# HTML is showing in the aura component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" controller="AccountController" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute type="campaign[]" name="acctList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
      
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAcc}"/>
      
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }"
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
      
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please have a look at: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value=""/>
```